# Why Does ForEach-object loop stop working when reading .CSV File

Tags: powershell

**UPDATE:**

I made the recommend changes.  I have switched over to switch statements instead.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\TEST\Test_Data.csv 

$rowcount = 1

ForEach ($line in $CSV) {
   
   $rowcount++
   
   $Store = $line.Store
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"A") = $Store

   $StoreNUM = $line.StoreNumber
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"B") = $StoreNUM
  
   $COLUMNA = $line.A
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNA) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNA
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNA
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNA
        }

    } #end Switch

   $COLUMNB = $line.B
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNB) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNB
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNB
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNB
        }

    } #end Switch

   $COLUMNC = $line.C
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNC) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNC
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNC
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNC
        }

    } #end Switch

   $COLUMND = $line.D
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMND) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMND
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMND
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMND
        }

    } #end Switch

   $COLUMNE = $line.E
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNE) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNE
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNE
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNE
        }

    } #end Switch

   $COLUMNF = $line.F
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNF) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared With:*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNF
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNF
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -like "Net Wt"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNF
        }

    } #end Switch

} #end Foreach
```

But I still have an issue in the Source CSV it is not moving past the 8th Column of data.  My data spans 17 Columns long.  I don't understand why it stops running through the columns.  There aren't empty Columns that I am aware of.  All of your help so far has been much appreciated.

---

Confused as to why my ForEach loop stops working.  Everything works properly until `####Evaluate Column E####` once it reaches E it stops searching.  Whatever I put for data in the CSV it gets totally ignored.  If I put the data in Column A - D it works just fine.

There is probably a easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish.

```
$csv = import-csv C:\TEST\Test_Data.csv 
$csv | foreach-object {
    
  $ItemName = $_.Filename
  $Store = $_.Store
  $StoreNUM =$_.StoreNumber
  $Department =$_.Department 
  $COLUMNA = $_.A
  $COLUMNB = $_.B
  $COLUMNC = $_.C
  $COLUMND = $_.D
  $COLUMNE = $_.E
  $COLUMNF = $_.F
  $COLUMNG = $_.G
  $COLUMNH = $_.H

}
$csv | ForEach-Object {$rowcount = 2}{

   $Store = $_.Store
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"A") = $Store

   $StoreNUM = $_.StoreNumber
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"B") = $StoreNUM

   $Department = $_.Department
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"C") = $Department

   $ItemName = $_.Filename
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"D") = $ItemName


####Evaluate Column A####
   $COLUMNA = $_.A

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNA -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNA
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMNA -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMNA
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMNA
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"Q") = $COLUMNA
   }

####Evaluate Column B#####
   $COLUMNB = $_.B

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNB -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNB
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMNB -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMNB
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMNB
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMNB -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMNB
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"R") = $COLUMNB
   }

####Evaluate Column C####
   $COLUMNC = $_.C

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNC -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNC
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMNC -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMNC
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMNC
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMNC -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMNC
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"S") = $COLUMNC
   }

####Evaluate Column D####
   $COLUMND = $_.D

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMND -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMND
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMND -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMND
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMND
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMND -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMND
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"T") = $COLUMND
   }

####Evaluate Column E####
   $COLUMNE = $_.E

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNE -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find Contains:
   if($COLUMNE -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNE
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMNE -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNE
   }


   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMNE
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMNE
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMNE -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMNE
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"U") = $COLUMNE
   } 

####Evaluate Column F####
   $COLUMNF = $_.F

   #Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNF -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNF
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find NEW UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*NEW*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"I") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"J") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find Label Type
   elseif($COLUMNF -clike "*LABEL*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNF
   }


   #Find Section
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Section:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"L") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find Retail
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Retail:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"M") = $COLUMNF
   }

   #Find Cost
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Cost:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"N") = $COLUMNF
   }
   
   #Find Requested By
   elseif($COLUMNF -like "*Requested by:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"O") = $COLUMNF
   }
   
   else{
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"V") = $COLUMNF
   }


    #Increase Row Count
    $rowcount++

}
```

Comment: `$csv | ForEach-Object {$rowcount = 2}` You might be leaving your foreach a little bit earlier than you had intended with thtat line.

Comment: @notjustme I did that so it would start on the second row.  The First row has headers which I don't want to over write.  There is a rowcounter at the bottom that runs the value up.  Which seems to be working properly.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the second line's forEach loop?  Why for each row of the CSV are you setting those variables?  What will happen is that only the items in the last row will take affect.

Comment: @FoxDeploy I think I understand what you mean I removed the first $CSV | ForEach-Object{   }.  It now starts at $CSV | Foreach Object {$rowcount = 2{  }

Comment: @FoxDeploy It didn't seem to have any effect.  I am going to leave it out though as I don't think it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I answered that I thought you were ending your loop early, but I was wrong.  I'd forgotten that `ForEach-Object` supports both `-Begin` and `-End` scriptblocks, which is what you were using.

For an example, here's a similar command but with the parameter names included.

```
1..3 | ForEach-Object `
    -Begin {"starting..."; $baseVar = "ham"} `
    -Process {"$basevar + $_"} `
    -End {"all done"}

starting...
ham + 1
ham + 2
ham + 3
all done
```

This is supported in PowerShell but practically never used.  I've been writing PowerShell for ten years at the enterprise level and it threw me for a loop.  I would caution against it.

One last thing, stylistically, you're doing so many If comparisons that it's pretty hard to keep track of your code.  I would simplify some of your code like this.

```
#Find Prepared With:
   if($COLUMNA -like "*Prepared*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find Contains:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Contains:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNA
   }
   
   #Find Net Weight:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*Net Wt.:*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNA
   }

   #Find OLD UPC:
   elseif($COLUMNA -like "*OLD*UPC*"){
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNA
   }
```

this code would be rewritten using a `switch` statement and look like this.

```
switch ($COLUMNA)
{
    {$_ -like "*Prepared*"}{   #Find Prepared With:
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNA
    }
    {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{  #Find Contains
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNA
    }
    {$_ -like "*Net Wt.:*"}{   #Find Net Weight:
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNA
    }
    {$_ -like "*OLD*UPC*"}{    #Find OLD UPC:
        $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $COLUMNA
    }
}
```

An even better approach would be to move that code into a function like, `Set-ColumnValue`

```
Function Set-ColumnValue{ 
    Param
        ($rowcount,
         $cellInfo
        )

    switch ($cellInfo)
    {
        {$_ -like "*Prepared*"}{   #Find Prepared With:
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $cellInfo
        }
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{  #Find Contains
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $cellInfo
        }
        {$_ -like "*Net Wt.:*"}{   #Find Net Weight:
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $cellInfo
        }
        {$_ -like "*OLD*UPC*"}{    #Find OLD UPC:
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"H") = $cellInfo
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd replace those if blocks with `Set-ColumnValue -rowCount $rowCount -CellInfo $columnA`

Edit: this below was incorrect

Like @notjustme is hinting, you're ending your `forEach-object` very early on.

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {$rowcount = 2}{

   $Store = $_.Store
```

So, to be specific, you're ending right here

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {$rowcount = 2} <==== Ends the forEach
```

Comment: All rowcount does is tell Sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") which row to print on.  I changed it to 10 and it did the exact same thing except for 10 rows down.

Comment: So there's your answer - you set your `$rowcount` to 10, which ends the loop at 10 - I'll explain in a separate answer with formatting that I hope will illuminate. Also, I very much endorse using a `Switch` statement rather than those `If`s.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a `Foreach-Object` pipelining your CSV file contents to one script block, but then you have another *entirely separate* scriptblock that has "inherited" the `$rowcount = 2` from the previous block.

All I'm doing below is adding some linebreaks, indents and comments to your code. Formatting your scripts with each scriptblock commencing on a separate line, indenting, and aligning the final bracket with the block's start line indent level can help troubleshoot.

```bsh
# process each CSV line
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $rowcount = 2
} # End Foreach-Object
 
# this starts a new block - $rowcount is definitely 2!
# but it's no longer processing each line of your CSV
{
   $Store = $_.Store
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"A") = $Store

   $StoreNUM = $_.StoreNumber
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"B") = $StoreNUM
   …
   $COLUMNA = $_.A
   … 
}
```

Another way to do the loop that might make it clear, if it still isn't:

```bsh
# since we're not using the pipeline, this is now a Foreach
# it's a lot faster than Foreach-Object for this kind of thing

ForEach ($line in $CSV) {
    $rowcount = 2
    # notice we've done nothing with $line!
}  # End Foreach
 
# the next block 
# $line will be set to the last line of the CSV processed above
{
    $Store = $line.Store
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"A") = $Store
 
    $StoreNUM = $line.StoreNumber
    $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"B") = $StoreNUM
    … 
    $COLUMNA = $line.A
    … 
}
```

And for the solution, what you really wanted to do is set `$rowcount = 2` *outside* your script block. You're not using it as a counter and incrementing it, so it shouldn't really be in there - you don't need to keep setting it with each line of your CSV.

Quite often you'll see people create a section near the beginning of their scripts to define "constants" like these - nothing special to it other than setting the value, but a section away from any loops it makes it clear that the variable isn't intended to change.

```bsh
# We're using Foreach again for speed - 
# Consumes more memory, but typically no big deal for a text file

$rowcount = 2

ForEach ($line in $CSV) {
   $Store = $line.Store
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"A") = $Store

   $StoreNUM = $line.StoreNumber
   $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"B") = $StoreNUM
   …
   $COLUMNA = $line.A
   # use that switch statement!
    switch ($COLUMNA) {
        # Find "Prepared With:"
        {$_ -like "*Prepared*"}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"E") = $COLUMNA
        }
        # Find "Contains"
        {$_ -like "*Contains:*"}{ 
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"F") = $COLUMNA
        }
        # You can do -match, it can be a little faster
        {$_ -match "Net Wt\."}{  
            $sheet.Cells.Item($rowcount,"G") = $COLUMNA
        }
       … 
    } #end Switch
} #end Foreach
```

Comment: I like your explanation but I think it too is incorrect.  `ForEach-Object` has a `-Begin` parameter which you literally never ever see used.  The questioner is using it though.  See my edit to my answer for more info.  I think you were right in that by setting the rowcount too high, he might be blowing through the input file.  We really need to see the input data to solve this.

Comment: @FoxDeploy I have updated my For Each loop to remove the -Begin Parameter.  But it looks like my main issues is that the For Each loop isn't moving through all the columns.

Comment: it was nothing to do with the `-Begin` parameter - the original code had two separate scriptblocks according to the bracket placement. Also, `Foreach-Object` behaves differently. Unless you're memory-constrained, ditch the pipeline and do the `ForEach` _statement_